# D3js collision not updating

Tags: javascript, d3.js, collision, force-layout

I'm trying to create an animated bubble chart using d3js. It seems to be working except for one small thing: when i animate the size of the nodes they start to overlap.

My co-worker and me have been at it all morning but we seem to be missing or overlooking something.

Our html/js:

```
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="twelve">2012</button>
</div>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(0.5)
    .gravity(0.2)
    .distance(500)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .distance( function(d){ return d.radius})
      .start();

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function(e) {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })

        var nodes = graph.nodes
        var q = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
      i = 0,
      n = nodes.length;

  while (++i < n) {
    q.visit(collide(nodes[i]));
  }

  svg.selectAll("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  });


  $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.buttons button').on('click', function(){
            var showYear = $(this).attr('id');
            node.transition()
            .duration(350)
            .attr("r", function(d){ return d[showYear]["radius"]})
            .style("fill", function(d){ return d[showYear]["color"]})
        });
    })



});


function collide(node) {

  var r = node.radius + 16,
      nx1 = node.x - r,
      nx2 = node.x + r,
      ny1 = node.y - r,
      ny2 = node.y + r;
  return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
      var x = node.x - quad.point.x,
          y = node.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = node.radius + quad.point.radius;
      if (l < r) {
        l = (l - r) / l * .5;
        node.x -= x *= l;
        node.y -= y *= l;
        quad.point.x += x;
        quad.point.y += y;
      }
    }
    return x1 > nx2
        || x2 < nx1
        || y1 > ny2
        || y2 < ny1;
  };

}



</script>

</body>
```

and this is our json file:

```
    {
      "nodes":[
        {
            "name":     "Country One",
            "radius":   40,
            "color":    "#ff0000",
            "twelve" : {
                "radius" : 60,
                "color" : "#0ff000"
                }
            },
            {
            "name":     "Country Two",
            "radius":   40,
            "color":    "#ffff00",
            "twelve" : {
                "radius" : 60,
                "color" : "#0ff000"
                }
            }

      ]
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the force layout after updating the sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collision detection is done based on the `radius` attribute of the nodes, but I suppose you're animating only the radius of your SVG circles, not the `radius` attribute of the data behind them.

Proposed solution:

```
node
    .each( function( d ) {
        d.radius = d[showYear]["radius"];
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(350)
    .attr("r", function(d){ return d.radius})
    .style("fill", function(d){ return d[showYear]["color"]})
```

What's also a bit odd in my opinion, but may be fine: At creation time there is a `d.radius`:

```
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
```

but later it becomes `d[showYear]["radius"];`. Keep in mind that the `d` object holds only data for **one** node, not all of them.

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal, Or at least an upvote. Worked perfectly (after recalling force.start()), thanks!

(The d[showYear]["radius"]; contains the new radius for the updated circle)